# Pass a color array for segments to THREE.LineSegments

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to visualize a spatial network and I am wondering if it is possible to change the color of individual line segments (edges in my case) in `THREE.LineSegments`. I am aware that I can pass individual colors if I define separate `THREE.Line` meshes for each segment, but I --am otherwise new to the subject and-- would also like to avoid the performance penalty this latter method incurs --given the problem size.

I would appreciate if you would point me in the right direction in case there is one.

Comment: Easy. See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_lines.html and replace `THREE.Line` with `THREE.LineSegments`. Specify the colors in pairs, so both ends of each line segment are assigned the same color.

Comment: @WestLangley, thank you so much, it works like a charm!