# Passing opacity to individual segments of THREE.LineSegments

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is a follow up on [passing a color array for segments to THREE.LineSegments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603515/pass-a-color-array-for-segments-to-three-linesegments) and I'm hoping to find and answer that avoids the topic of low-level shaders ([potentially relevant example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader.html)) to which I'm completely foreign.

So.. simply put: Is it possible to pass opacity to individual `THREE.BufferGeometry` color elements? Perhaps via a 4-vector color array without dipping toes into shader waters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I read [this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/shaders/) nice and short introduction to shaders for three.js and based on that I reduced the shaders used in the [potentially relevant example](https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_rawshader) I mentioned above to these basic versions,

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

 precision mediump float;
 precision mediump int;

 attribute vec4 color;
 varying vec4 vColor;

 void main()    {

   vColor = color;

   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

 }

</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

 precision mediump float;
 precision mediump int;

 varying vec4 vColor;

 void main()    {

   vec4 color = vec4( vColor );
   gl_FragColor = color;

 }

</script>
```

With these shaders, and using the `THREE.ShaderMaterial`,

```
 var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
   vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
   fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentShader').textContent,
   transparent: true,
   blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
   depthTest: false
 });
```

then populating the

```
 var colors = new Float32Array(segments * 4 * 2);
```

array with color + alpha values (hence the number **4**) and passing it to

```
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 4, true));
```

I was able to obtain the effect I was looking for. For disclosure, `segments` holds the number of segments I have in my `THREE.LineSegments` mesh and as **WestLangley** pointed out in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603515/pass-a-color-array-for-segments-to-three-linesegments) I need to pass in the color vectors twice (for both ends of a segment) which explains the additional factor of **2**. Fun ride; next stop: bring back `lineWidth` to the soup.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fiddle that illustrates how to create lines with alpha (or opacity) in three.js *without* using custom shaders. I pasted the most important lines below...
ref: https://jsfiddle.net/dtLfgab3/

```
  var edgeShaderMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.3
  });

  var lineSegments = new THREE.LineSegments(edgeGeometry, edgeShaderMaterial);
```